# Probability of drawing exactly k colors from a sample.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'm trying to solve exercise 3.3 from Jaynes' book on probability theory but my algorithm isn't suited for calculations and cannot provide results for big numbers like these. Here is the exercise:

Suppose we know that the urn contains exactly 50 balls but we don't know how many different colors there are. Drawing out 20 of them, we find three
different colors; now what do we know about $k$? We know from deductive reasoning
(i.e. with certainty) that $3 ≤ k ≤ 33$; but can you set narrower limits $k_1 ≤ k ≤ k_2$ within which it is highly likely to be?

Hint: This question goes beyond the sampling theory of this chapter because, like
most real scientific problems, the answer depends to some degree on our common
sense judgments; nevertheless, our rules of probability theory are quite capable of
dealing with it, and persons with reasonable common sense cannot differ appreciably
in their conclusions.

To be honest with you I have no idea how the hint is supposed to help here so I ignored it. Here is my attempted solution:

$C$: The urn contains exactly $50$ balls

$B$: We draw $20$ balls out of the urn and we find exactly three different colors

$A$: There are balls of $k$ different colors

With these statements I now want to find:
\begin{equation}
P(A|BC)=\frac{P(A|C)\cdot P(B|AC)}{P(B|C)}
\end{equation}

First $P(A|C)$, there are $\Omega_k$ ways in which fifty $k$ different colored balls can be in an urn:
\begin{equation}
\Omega_i=\frac{(50-1)!}{(50-k)!(k-1)!}
\end{equation}
If we assume equal a priori probability for each combination then:
\begin{equation}
P(A|C)=\frac{\Omega_k}{\sum_{i=1}^{50} \Omega_i}
\end{equation}

Next, I calculate $P(B|AC)$. The statement $AC$ is equivalent to $C(N_1+...N_k)$ where $N_i$ is a specific distribution of $k-$ colored balls so they add to $50$ in total. I use the following expression to calculate $P(B|AC)$:
\begin{equation}
p\left(B \mid N_{1} C+N_{2} C+\cdots+N_{n} X\right)=\frac{\sum_{i} p\left(N_{i} \mid C\right) p\left(B \mid N_{i} C\right)}{\sum_{i} p\left(N_{i} \mid C\right)}
\end{equation}

Due to equal a prior probability:

\begin{equation}
P(N_i)=\frac{1}{\Omega_k}
\end{equation}

And $P(B|N_iC)$ is calculated with the help of the generalized hypergeometric distribution where we take into account all possibles combinations that we draw exactly three colors. The distribution I mentioned:
\begin{equation}
h\left(r_{a}, r_{3}, \ldots, r_{k} \mid N_{a}, N_{3}, \ldots, N_{k}\right)=\frac{\left(\begin{array}{c}
N_{a} \\
r_{a}
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}
N_{3} \\
r_{3}
\end{array}\right) \cdots\left(\begin{array}{c}
N_{k} \\
r_{k}
\end{array}\right)}{\left(\begin{array}{c}
\sum N_{i} \\
\sum r_{i}
\end{array}\right)}
\end{equation}

Finally, for $P(B|C)$ we can take the statement $C$ and divide it into $C_1+...+C_{50}$ where $C_i$ The statement that there are $i$ colors in the urn. Using the same rule used for $P(B|AC)$ we can calculate this too.

For smaller numbers, this method works and the python code I wrote can handle it. For bigger numbers (like the ones in the original problem) my PC isn't able to handle it. I "solved" this problem like a robot would therefore the calculations for the statements $P(B|AC)$ are extremely time-consuming. Therefore I ask if there is a way to get a reasonable probability for statements like $P(B|AC)$ that don't involve taking all different possibilities into account. Thank you for taking the time to read this and sorry for the lengthy question.

Comment: It would be reasonable, say, to imagine that there were $k$ colors and that (a priori) each ball was equally likely to have any color.  You could then use a maximum likelihood argument to find the most probable $k$, given the observed result.

Comment: I don't know what the maximum likelihood argument is. I will look it up and try to use it though.

Comment: You could, say, compute (for each $k$) the probability that you'd observe exactly $3$ colors out of a sample of $20$.  Then take the $k$ for which this is maximal.  Hard to imagine that this gives anything other than $k=3$, though.

Comment: Still, you could set some cut off this way.  For instance, you could exclude all $k$ for which the probability that you'd see exactly $3$ colors was less than $X\%$ for some preset $X$.

Comment: I tried to compute the probability for each k, but my PC couldn't handle the program that I wrote (I'm not the best programmer either). Also, this kind of solution feels to me a bit like cheating because you just brute force calculate everything.

Comment: Well, you can simplify the computation.  For any given $k$, it is easy to compute the mean of the number of colors you see out of $20$.  A little more work gives you the variance.  Now just approximate and pretend that everything is normal, so the mean and variance let you estimate the probability that you see exactly $3$.  I don't see how you can avoid calculations, though are they really that bad?  I doubt, for example, that $k=6$ looks viable here.

Comment: I mean, for any $k$, you expect to see $k\times \left(1- \left(\frac {k-1}k\right)^{20}\right)$ colors, and for $k=6$, that comes to $5.84$   So it would be weird to see only $3$.

Comment: To do these calculations don't you have to take into account the different ways in which k colors can add up to 50 total balls?

Comment: Certainly not! $\quad$

Comment: Note:  you can, of course, relax the assumption that each color is equally likely, but we have no information at all on that so, to me, it seems better to just allow a few low probability $k$ in.  It would be nice if we had the distribution of each color amongst the $20$, but we don't.

Comment: I don't think I'm at a level where I can follow your thoughts easily. I will try to get a bit more acquainted with these things and then I will check your comments again.

Comment: @lulu Hello again, I am still struggling with this problem. I found a way to solve It algorithmically but it is very hard to put into actual use. If you have the time could you please explain how you found the average colors drawn out of a sample knowing only the different colors in the original urn?

Comment: I was modeling the problem by assuming that each color was a uniform draw from $k$ samples.  On reflection, though, it is probably wiser to just look at worst cases.  Say there are $3+N$ colors.  Then there are at least $N$ balls of unseen colors.  If $N$ were $10$ say then the chances of missing all $10$ of them in $20$ tries is $\binom {40}{20}\big / \binom {50}{20}\approx .003$.  Thus we can safely imagine that $N<10$.  Continue that way.

Comment: I tried your method by using a similar example with smaller numbers, so my PC could get a result. In this new example I used $20$ balls, I drew $5$ balls and saw $2$ colors. Say there are $6$ colors $(2+4)$ in the urn. My PC gives a possibility of $= 0.117$. While $\binom{20-4}{5}/ \binom{20}{5}=0.281$. These values don't agree, am I understanding something wrong again?

Comment: I don't know what calculation you are doing.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't clarify. I edited my original post where I describe what calculation gave me the result I mentioned

Comment: I wouldn't advise spending a lot of time on this question.  It all comes down to modeling.  What assumptions you make.  The model I described in my recent comments is, I think,  the most stripped down version.  But you could add more assumptions!  And that might change the answer, slightly.  But in practice one always knows more about a situation than one knows here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135105/discussion-between---and-lulu).

Comment: I really don't think there's anything to chat about.  Your calculation assumes that "equal a priori probability for each combination"  That is a fairly bizarre assumption, far from what one expects in the real world.  My early comments assumed that each of $k$ colors was equally likely for each draw, but that is also unsupported by the (scant) data.  My later comments didn't assume much of anything, but of course they produce the weakest estimate. Happily the range of estimates is not vast.  Even the weakest model appears to suggest that, say, $9$ colors is low probability.

Comment: I just wrote a thank you for taking your time to help me in the chat so I don't need to do it from here

Comment: Thanks very much!  And good luck on your studies,

Answer (score 2):

The main difficulty, probably, lies in understanding the phrase "within which it is highly likely to be". I shall interpret it according to the standard meaning for confidence interval in statistics, which is "Given confidence level $\alpha$ (say, the standard $0.05$), find an interval $[k_1,k_2]$ such that if the true number of colors $k$ is outside that interval, then, no matter what the distribution of colors is, the probability $P$ to observe exactly 3 colors in the random sample of 20 balls is less than $\alpha$". This calls for the worst case scenario, which is not so easy to determine. Fortunately, if we agree to consider only small $\alpha$ and, correspondingly, not too small $k$, we can safely say that $P$ is not very different from the larger probability $Q$ of seeing *at most* 3 colors. The latter is relatively easily seen to be maximized when we have $51-k$ balls of one color and $1$ ball of each other color. The direct computation in this case gives the following values of $P$ and $Q$ for this scenario (the worst $P$ is, of course, always underestimated here, quite severely in the beginning).

```
k              P                      Q

3       0.155102040816327       1
4       0.290816326530612       0.941836734693878
5       0.358879722101607       0.830460269214068
6       0.364080877494384       0.690029073609092
7       0.327672789744945       0.544396722611339
8       0.271074762425364       0.410348763170225
9       0.210135474748344       0.296875606806119
10      0.154385246753885       0.206817546199686
11      0.108257947418883       0.139038657380907
12      0.072773397987138       0.0903225810424096
13      0.0470228110070738      0.0567348588944997
14      0.0292486384254526      0.0344608957858858
15      0.017522832930564       0.0202318284437738
16      0.01010932669071        0.0114704119784918
17      0.00561170787729207     0.00627132968041236
18      0.0029929108678891      0.00330042551008127
19      0.00153046578471602     0.00166792867305085
20      0.000748352755026582    0.000807041669148088
21      0.000348694832091239    0.000372514263003621
22      0.000154159820503495    0.000163297363748878
23      6.43218561411135e-05    6.76119579191221e-05
24      2.51599097150614e-05    2.62621932569778e-05
25      9.14905807820415e-06    9.48892011360349e-06
26      3.05988564488433e-06    3.15495682869293e-06
27      9.2816531228158e-07     9.51839164376211e-07
28      2.50604634316027e-07    2.55715180165026e-07
29      5.86699812779995e-08    5.95898141785708e-08
30      1.14574374212928e-08    1.15871022238439e-08
31      1.75368940121829e-09    1.76644157702146e-09
32      1.87463349785404e-10    1.88121115925002e-10
33      1.05242582335665e-11    1.05242582335665e-11
```

This means that $k_1=3$ no matter what, while $k_2=9$ gives only the level of confidence between $0.15$ and $0.21$, which is not so great. To go to the customary $0.05$, we need to raise $k_2$ to $13$, and to get the $0.01$ level, we'll have to go up to $16$.

The Bayesian approach here doesn't seem adequate because there is no obvious natural prior to start with, so the results may vary quite a bit according to its choice. The worst case scenario analysis above may be a bit too pessimistic, of course, but lacking any other information, it is one of the most standard ways to formalize the problem.

Comment: Couldn't you consider the Best case scenario? For example, if there are $11$ colors in the Urn the best scenario for $3$ colors would be say $14$ Red, $14$ Blue, $14$ Green, and the remaining $8$ to be different colors. With this scenario, drawing exactly three colors gives a probability of  $0.01$ which is pretty small for the best scenario. This seems, to me at least, better than considering the worst-case scenario.

Comment: @ΜπαμπηςΠοζουκιδης That question is somewhat meta-mathematical. The worst case scenario consideration gives you a firm guarantee in the sense I described, while anything else gives only some hope that what you are saying might be true. As it was said already in the comments, the key point is what, in addition to what is given, you are willing to assume. I chose to assume nothing whatsoever, hence the worst case consideration. You are free to assume something else, of course, but then you'll have to argue why your assumptions are justified.

Comment: Three questions then:
1) If I could prove that this is indeed the best-case scenario, would this approach be just as valid as yours?
2) Since $P$ is easily calculated for a given distribution of balls, do you include $Q$ in your argument because you are confident what the worst-case scenario is for $Q$ to happen? 
3) Intuitively it makes sense that $P$ and $Q$ are similar, but can you say this with confidence because of the values you calculated or did you prove it some other way?

Comment: @ΜπαμπηςΠοζουκιδης  1) No. The best (or some) case scenario doesn't give the true guarantee. 2) Exactly. It is quite hard to figure out the worst case scenario for $P$, but relatively easy to do it for $Q$ and $Q$ dominates $P$, so the value of $k_2$ coming from $Q$ is completely reliable albeit it may be a bit suboptimal. 3) Because of the calculated values. You can, probably, attempt to prove it directly as well but I haven't tried it.

Comment: I think I understand why the worst-case scenario works, if the probability for the worst-case scenario is above a certain agreed-upon value we are good so to say. But why is it wrong to say that if the probability for the best-case scenario is below some value this is not good?